# Parentheses on string concatenation and returns

Tags: php

Usually i use parentheses when i write functions, conditions, math, etc...
But recently, I've seen some projects (including Wordpress) where they use parenthesis for other things like string concatenation and returns.

For example:

```
$MyVar = ('my string 1' . 'my string 2' . 'my string 3');
return (condition1 === true && condition2 === true && condition3 === true);
```

So why are they doing that? because i tested some code resembling the above examples, using parentheses, and i got the same result as without them. So what's the point? i know in math they have meaning, but here? Is it just a writing style?

Comment: given it's wordpress, I'll go with cargo-cult programming.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921843/php-returnvalue-vs-return-value

Comment: They're here for decoration only. There's no purpose other than a personal preference of the coder.

Answer (score 0):

It's only a convention, probably the programmer wanted to emphasize that the value returned / assigned is only one, even if there is an expression (that is evaluated before the return).

Answer (score 0):

A parenthesis defines boundaries. In some contexts they are mandatory, and in others they are just used to better organize and understand the code.

For e.g the following code is perfectly valid in PHP:

```
//perform cleanup
{
   var $isClean = false;
   $isClean = doCleanup();
}
```

It is the same as `$x = (1 + 2);`

Where the brackets are only used for clarity/grouping for human understand and not because the language syntax mandates it.